# Specifying child method with base class object in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection, refactoring, composition

I've written below snippet to produce better and reusable code in all of `Child` classes.

**Base Entity :**

```
public class BaseEntity{
     Integer id; 
     //setter getters etc
}
```

**Child Entity :**

```
public class MyChild extends BaseEntity{
    String name;
    //setter getters etc
}
```

I have many child classes that extends BaseEntity and want to write a method to remove `boilerplate` code.

**Util Class :**

```
public class Util{
    public String getName(BaseEntity base){
        return base != null ? base.getChild().getName() : "";
    } 
}
```

The problem is **base.getChild.name()** How to do something like that when child isn't in a `composition` form ?
I've reading about Java Reflection but don't know how to do it in an optimise way in this scenario.. Is there any better option than Reflection ?

Comment: given that `getName()` isn't defined on the base class, you need some sort of introspection to check if you can call that method on a given instance. You can do something like this `if (base instanceof MyChild) { ((MyChild) base).getName() }`

Comment: It's my assuming only to define the problem.. I've many childrens so can't specify each of them in my code.. Also i can't redesign the whole project entities. Any suggestion ?

Comment: do all subclasses have a `getName` method, or is the method you want to call different per class? Also, when you call the method do you know the type at compile time (i.e. can you cast your instance to the right sub class) or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Java Reflaction API then you can invoke "getName" method in such way:

```
Class<? extends BaseEntity> aClass = base.getClass();
Method method = aClass.getMethod("getName"); 
method.invoke(base);
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining default method and implementing the interface in BaseEntity can handle the scenario provided child entities follow same naming convention

```
interface defaultGetName{
    default String getName(){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("getName not defined for this class");
    }
}
@Data
class BaseEntity implements defaultGetName{
    Integer id;
    //setter getters etc
}
public class Util{
    public String getName(BaseEntity base){
        return base != null ? base.getChild().getName() : "";
    } 
}
```